# Failed to apply plugin 'org.akhikhl.gretty'

Tags: gradle, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

I am new to App engine, Gradle and IntelliJ. I have been trying to make a gradle project with Google app engine plugin and deploy it to app engine. I am following the doc provided by google "https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/using-gradle".
I am getting this error in the build.gradle file after I added the dependencies mentioned in the doc.
"A problem occurred evaluating project ':lib'.
Failed to apply plugin 'org.akhikhl.gretty'.
Cannot run Project.afterEvaluate(Closure) when the project is already evaluated."
Till now I have only downloaded intelliJ, created a gradle project and been following the doc. Am I missing something?

Comment: Without a bit more detail what JDK, Gradle version you are using, which code you try to compile, etc. it's hard to tell. The error might indicate that the used version of the plugin does not support Gradle >= 7.0.

Comment: This is still a problem! I also just followed the instructions on this page and I can't seem to get it to work. Did you end up finding a solution to the gretty issue?